# Insert into MySQL a variable that changes for each row

Tags: php, mysql

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlquery)) 
        {

    $fd = strtotime($row['date1']);
    $sd = strtotime($row['date2']);


    $dates = floor(($sd - $fd ) / 86400);

    $price = $dates * 25;
   }
```

I want to insert into another table the `$price` for each row. I cannot do this with a single insert because the `$price` is different each time.

Comment: what is the error? probably you could keep the $price in an array

Comment: the $price is just a calculation from the rows date1 and date2

Answer (score 2):

```
"INSERT INTO `yourtable` ('price') VALUES ('".$price."')";
```

Put that in the while loop, so

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlquery)) 
        {

    $fd = strtotime($row['date1']);
    $sd = strtotime($row['date2']);


    $dates = floor(($sd - $fd ) / 86400);

    $price = $dates * 25;
"INSERT INTO `yourtable` ('price') VALUES ('".$price."')";
   }
```

This means there will be an insert for every iteration of the while loop, with `$price` being different each time.

Comment: You could also change it to PDO / mysqli, which means you could convert it to use bound parameters, which will process the INSERTs more efficiently.

Comment: @andrewsi true, but i'm basing this on mysql because that was in the OP's question

Answer (score 1):

To insert all the rows at once you can do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Other_Table (price)
  SELECT 25 * (date2 - date1) / 86400
  FROM ... (table from $sqlquery)
  WHERE ... (where clause from $sqlquery)
```

Comment: that doesn't actually tell MySQL what values to insert

Comment: @imulsion - won't the statement insert a new row and set `price` to the calculated value for every row returned by the query? I tested using a similar query - not the exact one above - so I may have muffed it. Did I leave something out?

Comment: uh,  i thought INSERT statements need a VALUES parameter to tell mysql what to insert. It might be me >.<

Comment: No worries @imulsion. I used the `INSERT ... SELECT` flavor of MySQL for my answer. It's documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html). It's a pretty useful command. I reach for it at least a couple times per week, though mostly for one-offs like importing from another table or setting up test data. Oracle and SQL Server support it too.

Comment: oh I see :) I'm a bit of a PHP noob, this is my first PHP question answer.

Comment: Well for a first answer it was a good one - I voted it up this morning :) Keep at it! I started posting answers here a couple months ago just because I'd been using the site as a reference for so long and wanted to give back, but I find I've learned a *lot* since I started putting myself on the spot with answers. It's definitely sharpened my skills.

Comment: I love getting upvotes, so thanks! It makes me feel like I actually know what I'm talking about